# Rails Performance on Heroku: What is this New Relic report telling me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, newrelic

Our Rails site is experiencing intermittent performance issues. Example: In the last 4 days we have received two H12 "Request timeout" errors and one H13 "Connection closed without response". Each error came from a different API request on our site. There doesn't seem to be a pattern.

The bulk of the site is an API that our iOS and Android apps communicate with. The site is hosted with Heroku and we use 2 dynos. We are running Adept Scale to automatically scale the number of dynos.

We are running the free version of New Relic on the site and I am trying to use that to help pinpoint areas where we can improve performance. I am new to Ruby/Rails and have inherited this project.

The site uses Unicorn with 2 worker processes. The Unicorn timeout is set to 30 seconds.

According to new Relic, the dynos handled an average of 2 requests per minute in the last 7 days. This doesn't seem like a ton of traffic to me, but I may be wrong.

Not sure if this will help, but here is a sample report from New Relic for one of the transactions that has the "Slowest average response time". The transaction is "Api::V1::TransactionsController#create"

[image: New Relic Report]

I can see from the report that Braintree (our payment processor) is taking an average of 1,360ms, but this seems reasonable.

**Questions:**

Are these random H12 / H13 errors normal?

How do I determine the source of these problems if they are not coming from the same API call each time?